# GPG deleted key/disassociation

Tags: gnupg

I had a key that I accidentally deleted from the keyring a while ago and I'd like to dissociate my name from it. I still have the key as well as the revocation certificate. I made another keypair since then with an entirely different passphrase and I'd like to remove my name from the old one.

**Update:** When going to revoke the UID I wish to be rid of using the revuid command I am met with this message:

```
gpg --edit-key 0x123456789

sec  rsa4096/XXXXXXXXX
     created: 2029-03-14  expires: 2031-03-14  usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown

ssb  rsa4096/YYYYYYYYY
     created: 2029-03-14  expires: 2030-03-14  usage: E   
[ unknown] (1)* Name lastname (Hello) <example@email.com>

gpg> revuid 

Really revoke this user ID? (y/N) y

Please select the reason for the revocation:
  
0 = No reason specified
  
4 = User ID is no longer valid
  
Q = Cancel
(Probably you want to select 4 here)

Your decision? 4 
Enter an optional description; end it with an empty line:
> 
Reason for revocation: User ID is no longer valid

(No description given)
Is this okay? (y/N) y
gpg: Cannot revoke the last valid user ID.
```

*I suspect it has to do with the trust level of the UID I wish to revoke.*

Comment: Is that to say that you had generated the revocation for the old key, but had yet to revoke it from public servers, or only locally? And if you are revoking the old key, there shouldn't be a need to revoke your user ID from the old one as well.

Comment: Yeah I just went on and deleted the key without revoking it first. I was being quite foolish at the time. The issue is more that my user ID contained an important name so I just wanted to see if I could change that by adding a new uid and then deleting the rest, or something like that.

Comment: If you still have the original **private** key you should be able to re-import it into your keyring. If you are set on revoking that user ID from the key before fully revoking it, you may [delete the UID from the key](https://nowherelan.com/2011/01/18/delete-a-uid-from-a-gpg-key/) and publish it, then you may finish the public revocation process.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Would I import the file that contains my private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still have the original private key you can re-import it and then list all available keys:

```
gpg --import private.key
gpg --list-keys
```

It may be prudent to see what is available on public servers (feel free to change to whichever you utilized, unless set in your gpg configuration) before beginning (or restarting) this process - **if your key is already revoked according to public keyservers you will not be able to modify it** (that I'm aware of):

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --search-key 0x12345678
```

Then given you wish to revoke your user ID from the key, providing the correct key ID.

You will then be entered into the prompt to choose the correct identity (`uid #`) and modify the key, which you can use the `revuid` command context:

```
gpg --edit-key 0x12345678
gpg> uid 2
gpg> revuid
    Really revoke this user ID? (y/N) y
    Please select the reason for the revocation:
      0 = No reason specified
      4 = User ID is no longer valid
      Q = Cancel
    (Probably you want to select 4 here)
    Your decision? 4
```

**Note:** If there is a single identity left on the key you have to *create a new one on that key* as you ***cannot revoke the last remaining ID***, otherwise it is more prudent to just complete the revocation of the entire key.

If you have *two or more* identities on the key, you may continue with the rest of the steps in this answer.

As you have stated you desire to revoke the ID from the original key which I believe is extraneous given you will revoke the key entirely, but if that is what you want you can then push the update to the keyserver(s) where you originally published:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net -send-keys 0x12345678
```

Then you may complete the revocation process (which would require generating a new revocation certificate - the original revocation *should* no longer be in your keyring if you deleted the original key):

```
gpg --output revoke-old-key.asc --gen-revoke 0x12345678
gpg --import revoke-old.asc
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --send-keys 0x12345678
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I also have an ssb I wanted to delete. Would I use the delkey command to delete the ssb then revoke the uid?

Comment: You're welcome! That would likely be grounds for a separate question. If the `ssb` (secrete subkey) is a part of the key you're revoking and deleting, that should be unnecessary as it would be revoked already.

Comment: Thanks again! When I try to revoke it, I get this message: Cannot revoke the last valid user ID. Do I have to generate a private key for the new keypair?

Comment: I would update your original question with the steps you are doing so that I can tailor the answer to fit where you are getting stuck. Make sure to remove personal information in the output and make sure you are selecting the proper uid on the proper key. As for revoking you shouldn't have to generate a new private key, but if you need a separate key, then yes.

Comment: Just updated the question, thank you for all your help so far

Comment: No problem! Updated answer with a note: basically if you have only the last remaining identity on a key you cannot revoke it. Feel free to add upvotes to answers and comments to show that they helped you! ^_^